# Is there a way to click on a p:messages element to close it?

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces

Is there a way to add an `onclick` event to close the p:messages tag when clicked? 
By the way I have also noticed that it contains an X for close but clicking on it does nothing.

Here is the code of the `p:messages` tag:

```
<p:messages id="alarmMessages">
    <script>
        jQuery('#alarmMessages').effect("pulsate", {times:5}, 1000 );
        jQuery('#alarmMessages').show();
    </script>
</p:messages>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you're using JQuery, I suggest you add an event to some button or link that closes the messages. I don't know the code of your page you can add this event in document.ready:

```
$('#closeButtonId').click(function() {
    $('#alarmMessages').hide(); // you can also use fadeOut()
})
```

You can add that event to the panel itself, tough it won't ve very intuitive. I'd add a little close link below the down-right corner of the message panel.

On the other hand, you can add an event to the panel to hide it after a set amount of time, but that depends on your implementation and what you think is right. Just add an event to your panel in the document.ready funcion:

```
$('#alarmMessages').delay(5000).fadeOut(); // you can also use setTimeOut if you like.
```

Note: The X button you're talking about can be, in fact, an error icon. Is it a white X in red background?.

Comment: Yes..figured out the X is really related to error message and not closable X...:)

I was hoping I didn't have to add a button to do it and just be able to click on the JSF message itself to close it.  Is it not possible to close a JSF message or is the problem having to do with the way I am doing it with the <p:messages/> tag?

Comment: the p:messages component renders the messages it gets either from validation or from your methods (if you add messages such as "server error" or the like). It just renders the messages until the next request is issued, reloading the component and displaying the new messages. You're using it right, it just doesn't fade away by itself.

Comment: By the way, you can add the fadeOut event to the rendered component itself instead of a link. It's just that users won't know at first that they can close the messages by clicking on them. If you're using templates and your component id contains :'s you'll have to get it by using the type of component and the id attribute on it, like this: `$('div[id="form:alarmMessages"]')`

Comment: I used the hide function and it works great!  Now I need to figure out how to call a method in the backing bean - is there a way to do that from the Javascript?

Comment: If you just want to invoke a method (no parameters) you can use a p:commandLink with style="display:none" and invoke its click function in your javascript. If you need further help, please post a new question so we can fully understand the context of your needs :). There might be better answers but you'll need to post your intentions (comments are way too short, that's why I suggest a new question).